# Ant design change the components size globally

Tags: reactjs, antd

Ant design components have an attribute called (size) where you can change the size of the component between (small, medium, large) I want to change all the component sizes to large globally

I've already tried to change the size using the [theme customizer](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) that ant design provides but didn't work

```
      <ConfigProvider
        theme={{
          token: {
            size: "large"
          },
        }}
      >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `componentSize="large"` prop to ConfigProvider to change component sizes globally

```
<ConfigProvider componentSize='large' theme={{ ... }}></ConfigProvider
```